# EF6/Monodevelop or rider how do i generate csdl/mdl/ssdl resources?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6, mono, monodevelop, rider

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get monodevelop or rider to generate the edmx's csdl/ssl/mdl files. This is something simple I'm overlooking, right?

Comment: did you read the actual answer before writing that non constructive comment. I, before answering that, actually went onto a chat channel with a dev from the VS for Mac team, who then explained why its not supported. What you want to achieve with .NET classic is NOT supported on mono, and isn't in the roadmap. There are 2 viable alternatives listed which you can use/not use at this stage. All of the above still doesn't detract from the fact that your question is actually a duplicate of the linked question. Anyhow. Goodluck hunting for whatever answer you're looking for.

Comment: yeah sorry, just mad that i wasted days on mono, rider, monodevelop. just to tell my boss it has to be migrated to dotnetcore to run on linux servers.

Comment: No problem :) I spent about a week on that if not more... Prior to even asking on SO. Believe me I tried EVERYTHING. From getting deps from windows machines, altering parts of the internals of the build process, etc. Not worth the struggle. Classic is being phased out anyway... So I guess... Erm good riddance :P

Comment: on the upside i can do dotnet core with rider in linux ;)